# workflow c# expression properties window displays snippets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, editor, workflow, expression

I have been building workflows using VS2012 and .NET 4.5. However every now and then when I try and enter a C# expression in the editor window the intellisense does not pick up any variables or namespaces in the project. Instead it just lists code snippets available! It take a few attempts of opening and closing the window before I get the editor to behave as expected. Also, even though I am then able to enter the right expression, the designer will still flag an error because it cannot find the variables I have used. Please see attached image.[image]