# Workflow designer asking for generated file reload every time C# expression is edited in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, designer

I'm using VS2012 and .net 4.5. Whenever I edit C# expression in properties window I get message as shown in below image

Update: 
I did not open this file. Neither in VS nor in other program. I think VS loads this file for some reason.

[image: Error while editing C# expression]

If I open C# expression dialog I get similar behavior to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156947/workflow-c-sharp-expression-properties-window-displays-snippets)

I also often get error saying that VS cannot access this 'TemporaryGeneraterdFile_' cos it's being used by another process.

[image]

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/10848abc-f206-4d97-9221-c46341a53af2/vs-2012-workflow-designer-ioexception-process-cannot-access-the-file?forum=wfprerelease) post describes that error.

Did anyone experienced similar behavior?
It's realy anoing as it happens very often.

Comment: That's not really an error. It's the IDE asking you whether you want to reload the version of the document you have open since it has been edited.

Comment: @DGibbs Yes I would agree with that statement if I was the one loading this file and if this wouldn't happened every single time I try to edit c# expression. I will rephrase it to not mention 'error' to make it more clear. Could down-voter explain why ?

Comment: you have erroneously open an auto generated file. Close it and this would never appear again.

Comment: @FelicePollano I did not open this file. Neither in VS nor in other program.

Comment: I can confirm @LukaszSalamon . I'm having the same problem as well, in Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5